# What are some good references on the Galois theory, factorization, or minimality of differential equations?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, differential-equations, galois-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a nonzero complex number and let $u(x)$ be some smooth function $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$, not identically zero. I want to prove that if $u$ satisfies $$u'' + \lambda u'+ \lambda^2 u = 0 \qquad (*)$$then it doesn't solve some lower-order differential equation, say, $u' + \lambda u = 0$. Now, in this particular example, I can substitute $u' = - \lambda u$ into (*) to get
$$ \lambda^2 u - \lambda^2u + \lambda^2u = \lambda^2 u = 0$$
which is false by the hypotheses that neither $u$ nor $\lambda$ is zero. However, this may not work in general, when I have some differential equation satisfied by $u$ and want to prove that $u$ therefore may not satisfy some other differential equation.

(In the case that the equations are linear, I want to say that if $u$ satisfies a given equation of order $n$ that it may not satisfy one of order $m < n$, but I'm not sure yet if I'll be generalizing to a non-linear case as well.)

I therefore would like to learn what I can about the Galois theory, minimality, and factorization of differential equations. I currently have access to Singer and van der Put's [*Galois Theory of Linear Differential Equations*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540442286) but have so far been unsuccessful in making it through that book, so I'm looking for additional sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned already the book of van der Put and Singer, which is a standard reference for the Galois Theory of linear differential equations.

Other books on the topic include:

- Teresa Crespo and Zbigniew Hajto. Algebraic groups and differential Galois theory, volume 122 of Graduate Studies in Mathematics, American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2011.
- Irving Kaplansky. An Introduction to Differential Algebra. Hermann, Paris, 2nd edition edition, 1976.
- Andy R. Magid. Lectures on differential Galois theory, volume 7 of University Lecture Series. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 1994.

Comment: Michio Kuga _Galois' Dream: Group Theory and Differential Equations_ Birkäuser, 1993 is also worth mentioning.